# filtering a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, data-science

**This is my code**:

```py
import csv
import os

filename = "StudentsPerformance.csv"
file = open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8")
contents = csv.reader(file)


students = []
column_names = next(contents)
for row in contents:
    student = {
        "gender": row[0],
        "race/ethnicity": row[1],
        "parental level of education": row[2],
        "lunch": row[3],
        "test preparation course": row[4],
        "math score": row[5],
        "reading score": row[6],
        "writing score": row[7],
    }
    students.append(student)




def math_scores(student):
    return int(student["math score"])


def average_math_scores(student):
    scores = list(map(math_scores, students))
    total_scores = sum(scores)
    number_of_scores = len(scores)
    average_scores = total_scores / number_of_scores
    print(average_scores)
    return average_scores



if __name__ == '__main__':
    average_math_scores(students)
```

how can I make a filter so that male and female gets their own dict.
So that I have a dict call female with all of their data and same for male.
I have already defined the two dicts called female and male.

Comment: Just check `if row[0] == "male"` and `elif row[0] == "female"` and depending on the result append to different lists.

Answer (score 5):

Using python3

I assume this is your data, the code should work for more fields as well:

```
students=[{"gender":'m',"math_score":'A'},
          {"gender":'f',"math_score":'B'},
          {"gender":'m',"math_score":'D'},
          {"gender":'f',"math_score":'C'}]
```

You can use built-in `filter` function:

```
males=list(filter(lambda x:x["gender"]=='m',students))
females=list(filter(lambda x:x["gender"]=='f',students))
```

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) of filter function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use List Comprehension to filter out each list.

```py
males = [s for s in students if s['gender'] == 'male']
females = [s for s in students if s['gender'] == 'female']
```

You can also use the `filter()` function.

```py
males = filter(lambda x: x['gender'] == 'male', students)
females = filter(lambda x: x['gender'] == 'female', students)
```

*NOTE:* `filter()` returns an iterator, not a list.

[Reference](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-filter-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension can come in handy here:

```
males = [x for x in students if x["gender"] == "male"]
females = [x for x in students if x["gender"] == "female"]
```

Comment: actually made a mistake in the question a want males and females to be stored in dicts